# Make VScroll disabled instead of hidden in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, user-interface

Is there any way to make vertical scrollbar look disabled instead of hidden in ListView?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027931/how-can-i-customized-my-list-view-horizental-scrollbar-appearence) question.

Comment: @BrianS: this is question is about `windows forms` the link you posted, instead, is about `wpf`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I need to pay closer attention to tags.

Comment: Not an option, the native control forces the WS_VSCROLL style off.

Comment: Actually I can force it but then scrollbar becomes unthemed.

Comment: You could try sub-classing the listview, and catch WM_STYLECHANGING messages and force the WS_VSCROLL style on. I don't know if this would work though.

Answer (score 1):

[image]set in your designer a vscrollbar control on the right side of your ListView and make its propertie enable to false

Comment: It can't be done from designer ,but I could add it from code. The problem is when real scrollbar shows up I have two of them. I could probably do something with ClientSize canged ,but I thought there is a better way.

Comment: you can disable Vscroll of your listview and only allow the vscrollbar control, you can also make a user control with listview (vscrollbar disabling) and a vscrollbar that you will control.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the scrollbar to show by calling the native [ShowScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API via [P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowScrollBar.html):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bShow);
```

Comment: It ads enabled scrollbar which disapere with every Invalidate.

Comment: You can disable the scrollbar using P/Invoke as well. As for how to get around the Invalidate issue cleanly without dropping down to native code...not sure.

Comment: But I need disabled look , ShowScrollbar only show it or hides it.

Comment: P/Invoke into EnableScrollBar (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enablescrollbar). Does the scrollbar still disappear on invalidate even when it's disabled?